# How can I fade in/out an image to make effect that the screen get dark slowly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The fade script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class FadeToBlackInOut : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image blackScreen;
    public float fadeToBlackDuration;

    public void FadeToBlack()
    {
        blackScreen.color = Color.black;
        blackScreen.canvasRenderer.SetAlpha(0.0f);
        blackScreen.CrossFadeAlpha(1.0f, fadeToBlackDuration, false);
    }

    public void FadeFromBlack()
    {
        blackScreen.color = Color.black;
        blackScreen.canvasRenderer.SetAlpha(1.0f);
        blackScreen.CrossFadeAlpha(0.0f, fadeToBlackDuration, false);
    }
}
```

The script that use it :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class AnimationPlay : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject head;
    public GameObject[] cameras;
    public FadeToBlackInOut fadetoblackinout;

    private Animator anim;
    private bool started = true;
    private float animationLenth;
    private bool rotateHead = false;
    private bool isFinishedTurning = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (started == true)
        {
            anim.enabled = true;
            anim.Play("Stand Up", 0, 0);
            animationLenth = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).length;
            StartCoroutine(AnimationEnded());
            started = false;
        }

        if (rotateHead == true)
        {
            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(head.transform.localRotation.x, head.transform.localRotation.y, 0f);
            head.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Lerp(head.transform.localRotation, targetRotation, 1.0f * Time.deltaTime);

            // Check whether the current localRotation is the same as the target rotation
            if (head.transform.localRotation == targetRotation)
            {
                isFinishedTurning = true;
            }
        }

        // If the rotation is complete, swap cameras and disable animation
        if (isFinishedTurning == true)
        {
            fadetoblackinout.FadeToBlack();

            /*cameras[0].SetActive(false);
            cameras[1].SetActive(true);*/
            anim.enabled = false;
            isFinishedTurning = false;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator AnimationEnded()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(animationLenth);
        anim.enabled = false;
        rotateHead = true;
    }
}
```

I want at this part to fade slowly to black and then switch the cameras and then fade it back slowly from black :

```
if (isFinishedTurning == true)
            {
                fadetoblackinout.FadeToBlack();
    
                /*cameras[0].SetActive(false);
                cameras[1].SetActive(true);*/
                anim.enabled = false;
                isFinishedTurning = false;
            }
```

but when fading to black it does nothing. It's changing the image alpha color but it's not changing anything on screen.

This is a screenshot of the fade to black object with the script settings :

[Fade to black script settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kii6p.jpg)

This screenshot is the canvas settings :

[Canvas settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpZuk.jpg)

Screenshot of the Image settings the game start when the alpha color is 0 :

[Image alpha color is 0 by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNhNA.jpg)

and this screenshot is when the image alpha color is set to 255 when the game is not running,  but when I'm running the game I see in the inspector that the alpha color is 255 but still the game view window is not black.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMpMt.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd prefer to leave this as a comment, as it's not directly answering your question; however, I don't have enough reputation to comment.

You would probably be better off using a post processing effect using [one of Unity's three post processing stacks](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PostProcessingOverview.html), depending on the render pipeline you're using.

You can probably change the values of a vignette to encompass the entire screen, though otherwise it's not hard to [write your own post effects](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.postprocessing@2.1/manual/Writing-Custom-Effects.html) if they're simple enough.

It's of note that Screen Space - Overlay type UIs will render *after* the post processing stage though, so you should use this with world space or camera space canvases.